# Cannot find protocol declaration for protocol in Swift-Headers.h defined in Package

Tags: swift, objective-c, xcode

I got a compilation error.

XCode did not see the protocol that had been defined in a Package.
It was used as a requirement for a class.

```
class TestClass: NSViewController, ProtocolFromPackage {
    
}
```

In Swift-Headers.h I got an error:

> < path to compilation directory >/DerivedSources/Swift-Headers.h:5911:118: Cannot find protocol declaration for 'ProtocolFromPackage'; did you mean 'SomeOtherProtocol'?

Answer (score -1):

Just add a random dummy protocol with a property with the type of protocol that causes the error. Dont forget to use `@objc` with the dummy protocol.

```
@objc protocol PleaseJustFixCompilation: AnyObject {
    /*
     It's needed just to let Swift-header know that ProtocolFromPackage from Package exists.
     */
    var dummyProperty: ProtocolFromPackage? { get }
}
```

It might also require adding into some header:

```
@protocol ObservableBooleanListener;
```

Comment: This one is not working. Can you give more explanation for this.